# Can we store alphanumeric values in int data type

Tags: c

Can alphanumeric values be stored in an int data type or do we need a char to store it?

Comment: Originally, 50% of this question was tags and thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alphanumeric values are not values. They are numbers like everything else, but they follow a specified mapping *numer -> character*.

For example character 'A' is `65` according to ASCII encoding. The only difference is how you treat them: if you treat them as numbers then you print out them as numbers, otherwise you print their encoding. A `char` data type is just an `int` which has size of 1 byte. Just because 1 byte is enough to store the whole extended ASCII table. There is no real 'character' data type.

Short answer: yes.

Comment: ye sorry, forgot to conclude that :)

Comment: Unless he tries something bizarre like `if(val == 'A')...else if (val == 65)`, thinking that he can store both alphabetic and numeric "values" in an `int` and think they're two different things.

Comment: Yes, that would be bizarre, but I guess it already happened somewhere in the world :)

Comment: Haha yeah I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: @Ignacio: do you prefer high ASCII? or EASCII? or what?

Comment: "any single-byte character set (e.g. CP437, Latin-1, etc.)"

Comment: oh, well, you are right but that would make him open another question to explain what is a "single-byte character set".. don't make it complex :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can store characters in `int` data types.  A `char` is just a integer data type like `int`, but with a narrower guaranteed range.

In fact, it is sometimes the right thing to do to use `int` rather than `char` to store a character - for example, if you are reading characters from a file, you can use:

```
int c;

while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
{
    /* Do something with c */
```

In this case, you must use `int` rather than `char` for the type of `c` in order to be able to distinguish `EOF` from a valid character.

Answer (score 1):

char is a single byte datatype (and hence can have values from 0 to 255).

It has a `number -> char` mappping.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char c = 'a';
  int n = c;
  printf("Character '%c' stored in int as %d\n", c, n);
}
```

Output:

```
Character 'a' stored in int as 97
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store characters in `int` data types. A `char` is an integer data type like `int` that can be stored in a single byte. The `char` data type is capable of storing the ASCII character set (256 characters). The ASCII mapping maps numbers in the range of 0-255 to characters. Since `char` is an integer data type, you can store the number associated with the character in the `int`through assignment operation