# Saving an alphanumeric value in an array that is part of a structure

Tags: c, arrays, struct

In the below code I am defining a structure that only has one variable for now: `alphanumeric_code`. This variable is an array with 10 values, and should be able to store any alphanumeric value the user enters (i.e. abc123). My questions are:

- How can I store the value the user enters using the secondary function: `product_details()`?
- Defining an alphanumeric array as `int` is the best approach, right? According to this other answer: [Can we store alphanumeric values in int data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924815/can-we-store-alphanumeric-values-in-int-data-type), it seems to be the case.

Thank you very much guys! :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int alphanumeric_code[10];
} product_structure;

void product_details(product_structure *user_details);

int main()
{
    product_structure user_details;

    product_details(&user_details);

    return 0;
}

void product_details(product_structure *user_details)
{
    int i = 0;

    puts("Please enter the alphanumeric value:");
    scanf("%d", &(user_details -> alphanumeric_code[10]));
    
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("%c", user_details -> alphanumeric_code[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Defining an alphanumeric array as int is the best approach, right?" --> an array of `char` or even `unsigned char` would make more sense.  Linked answer refers to possibilities, not recommended practice.

Comment: "be able to store any alphanumeric value the user enters (i.e. abc123)" and `int alphanumeric_code[10];` is unclear.  What if input is more than 10  alphanumerics, what should happen?

Comment: Apologies @chux-ReinstateMonica, I wasn't clear. The array should only hold a maximum of ten values — that is why. Thank you!